# Is it possible to let highcharts radar-chart render the overflow parts?

Tags: highcharts, radar-chart

Given a max number to the yAxis, for example:

```
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max:5
  },
```

The chart will look like this:

[image]

However, is it possible to render the outer part? Just like the following below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `yAxis.min` and `yAxis.max`, you can define `tickPositions` and disable `endOnTick` for `yAxis` and set `offset` for `xAxis`. For example:

```
  yAxis: {
    endOnTick: false,
    tickPositions: [0, 2, 4, 6]
  },
  xAxis: {
    offset: 62
  },
  pane: {
    size: '100%'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o0w1v83e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

---

Another way is to overwrite Highcharts clipping behaviour.

```
(function(H) {
  H.SVGElement.prototype.clip = function() {};

  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'isPointInside', function(proceed) {
    return true;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/otchz6vL/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts